# Arrays with loop

Tags: java, arrays

how do i print diagonal String??(sorry my bad. i want to display DIAGONAL string )

Diagonal because my arrays has a pattern of diagonal zeroes.

please help....
heres my new code

```
public class Matrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int A[][]=     {{1,2,3,4,0},
                        {6,7,8,0,8},
                        {7,6,0,4,3},
                        {2,0,2,3,4},
                        {0,6,7,8,9}};

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
            {
                if ((A[i][j]==A[0][4])||(A[i][j]==A[1][3])
                        ||(A[i][j]==A[2][2])||(A[i][j]==A[3][1])||(A[i][j]==A[4][0]))
                    {

                System.out.println("Diagonal");
                }
            System.out.print(A[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone try this code and notice its output..

Answer (score 2):

```
int A[][]={
                    {1,2,3,4,0},
                    {6,7,8,0,8},
                    {7,6,0,4,3},
                    {2,0,2,3,4},
                    {0,6,7,8,9}
              };

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{

 System.out.print(A[i][i]+" ");
}
```

a single for loop will do!!!

Answer (score 1):

If i==j that will be your diagonal elements.

I need more clarity when you say you want to print other elements as well, all other except identified diagonal can be printed.

Comment: thank you for respone. heres the real Q.

Write a program that will read an n x n matrix into a two-dimensional array A and then determine which, if any, of
the following special cases the matrix falls into:
Symmetric: A[i][j] = A[j][i] for all i and j
Diagonal: A[i][j] = 0 whenever i and j are different
Upper Triangular: A[i][j] = 0 whenever i < j
Lower Triangular: A[i][j] = 0 whenever i > j

Comment: sorry, i mean i want to display string DIAGONAL if the elements has diagonal zeroes

Comment: "and i created my own ARRAYS, the thing is i manage to display my array. but after i puut the condition, the tables of my array are ruinned" what do you mean by tables of array are ruined ?

Comment: this is the output


1 2 3 4 Diagonal
0 
6 7 8 Diagonal
0 8 
7 6 Diagonal
0 4 3 
2 Diagonal
0 2 3 4 
Diagonal
0 6 7 8 9

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which diagonal. One diagonal is `i == j`. The second diagonal is `i + j == n - 1` (n = 5 in your case).

Comment: uhmm, okay i'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Neji's answer will print the diagonals (0, 0), (1, 1), (2,2), etc. which I don't think is what you wanted.

To see what your 2D array actually looks like (because we're not inserting elements into the 2D array as it appears in how you specify your array) we have to print arrays A[0]...A[i] on a new line each.

To see what your 2D array actually looks like:

```
int k = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < A[k].length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < A.length; x++) {
            System.out.print(A[x][y] + " ");
            k = x;
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

To see only the diagonals in your example input:

```
int k = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < A[k].length; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < A.length; y++) {
        int z = Math.abs(A.length - 1 - x);
        if (y == z) { 
            System.out.print(A[x][y]);
        } else {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
    }
    k = x;
    System.out.println("");
}
```